# JavaScript: the event object

Tags: javascript

Why can the event object have no properties? I get this error in Mozilla Firefox while in IE and Opera all is well.

Please, follow this link to see the problem: *here was the link*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** (now that a link is available): the problem is that you are attaching `handleMove` as the event handler which receives the event argument, then calling `documentRelative` and attempting to get the event object in there - but you never pass the event argument along.

Change lines 54 and 55 as follows:

```
function handleMove(e) {
    var documRelative = documentRelative(e);
```

or move

```
var e = (e) ? e : window.event;
```

from `documentRelative` to the start of `handleMove` and pass it into `documentRelative`.

Comment: I added a link to the page with the script.

Comment: I changed (as you can see on the page) lines 54 and 55 but there's no affect.

Comment: You are also calling documentRelative from elementRelative; you'll have to pass the event object through there, too. I would suggest installing the Firebug extension and using its JS debugger to track these things down.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. Also, now I understand this whole pass-event thing.